# Php - multiple domains in one $url statement not working

Tags: php, preg-match

so i'm trying to get the following working

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if ($url == url1.com or url2.com) {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

if i use just one domain name it works twice, if I use more than one separate by or or || then it matches the rule whatever the domain is (e.g. url3.com will load up everything in the first if statement despite it not matching either domain. What is the correct way to do this then?

Comment: Do you even know the syntax of `php` ?

Comment: You should probably fix your errors first. The urls are string, you are missing the closing parenthesis in the if statement, you have a random semi-colon after the closing curly brace.

Comment: So, no matter what matches or doesn't match you want to `echo '';`?  That is easier without the `if`.

Comment: Sorry I posted the question quickly, excuse the mistakes elsewhere I was more concerned with the if statement, but I've now fixed it with an array, id just hastily deleted the code in the middle to post on stack.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out already, silly, I should have used an array, hope this helps someone else

```
if (in_array($url, array("url2.com", "url1.com", "url4.com")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying:

```
if ($x == ('a' or 'b' or 'c')) { ... }
```

"do a boolean `or` of all those strings" and then see if the result of all that is equal to $x":

```
if ($x == true) { ... }
```

You want

```
if (($x == 'a') or ($x == 'b') or ....)) {
```

and if you have to test a LOT of different strings, then consider something like

```
if (in_array($x, array('a', 'b', 'c', ..... 'z'))) {
```

instead.